# How to get the icon on the right top of the images being added to the thumbnails?

Tags: javascript

this is my code...I tried giving the *style="position: relative; right:0; top:0;"* in the  tag. but, it fails to appear in that position.

//style tag

```
.thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
span.innerHTML = [
    '<a href="#" class="delete" id="x"><i class=" icon-remove-sign "position: relative;
    style="top:0; right:0;" ></i><img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" width="130" height="150"/></a>' 
].join('');
     document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` instead, but make if it breaks the flow, set the anchor's `position` to `relative`. You can also make the anchor an `inline-block` element.

Your code sample also has some invalid HTML. Move the `<i>` tag to after the `<img>` tag.

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCA8x/) for a sample of HTML & CSS

Comment: if position is made to absolute then it will appear on the right top corner of the page and not on that of the thumbnail image.

Comment: That is why you need to make the anchor's `position` `relative`.

Comment: @Shruthi make sure to add `display:inline-block;` to your anchor.

Comment: that also fails to work...tried adding  _display:inline-block;_